# Different methods to use Combo boxes and button click events in MVVM using C#?

Tags: c#, mvvm

What are the different methods to use combo boxes and button click events in **MVVM** using C# ?  Among them which is the best method and why it is best?

For example:
For Button click event,we can use **Command="{Binding command_name}"** in View.xaml and we can use **ICommand using RelayCommand** in ViewModel.cs.

Likewise what are the different ways to implement these events and which is the best method among them.
Here I'm not trying any code .I'm preparing a document in which I have to mention different ways to implement Button click events,Combo boxes (in MVVM).
As I mentioned in  above example for button click event, we can use **ICommand** and also **CallMethodAction**.Among these two methods which is best method, If Suppose **ICommand** is best,I have to write "why **ICommand** is better than **CallMethodAction**".

Likewise,Is there any other ways to assign the values for Combo boxes or only **binding** can be used.If suppose **binding** is the best method for it,then I have to write **how I'm saying binding is better than other methods**.

Please help me....Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The best method is NOT to trigger it. You should play with your viewmodel programmatically, the UI is for the user.

Comment: Yeah...I edit my question ..Please help me @CodingYoshi

Comment: help me please @Gaurang Dave

Comment: I assume that you are new to WPF and MVVM. I would suggest you to read and understand different article and sample available online easily. Your question is to broad to answer. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/  and https://www.dotnetforall.com/combobox-binding-in-wpf-using-mvvm/

Comment: @Madhu better you edit and ask particular question about your scenario, code and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited my question ...Please look over it @Gaurang Dave

Comment: @Madhu Are you preparing any assignment? SO is for code issue and any other issue while working on programming related stuff.

Comment: You can search over internet. You will find lots of material easily. https://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/07/22/commands-versus-event-triggers-in-mvvm/

Comment: @Gaurang Dave  I just want to know the name of the different methods used for button click events and combo boxes.So that I can search about it...Thats why I posted the question.

Comment: This is not a question for stackoverflow but something you need to research on your own. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581585/wpf-mvvm-command-vs-callmethodaction) may help you a little.